# Get status from multidimensional array with same key name in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 29
            [name] => User1
            [activated] => 1
            [profit_percentage] => 34.0000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [name] => User2
            [activated] => 1
            [profit_percentage] => 
        )

)
```

From this array I need to take a status by using the `profit_percentage` if any one of the `profit_percentage` has value mean I need to get status like  **profit is exists for at least one user**..

Suppose If my array is like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 29
            [name] => User1
            [activated] => 1
            [profit_percentage] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [name] => User2
            [activated] => 1
            [profit_percentage] => 
        )

)
```

Then the status must be like **profit does not exists**

How should I get this?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: I need to get an status string as 0 or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if your data in the variable `$data_array` then do sothing like following

```
$count = 0;
foreach($data_array as $data){
    if($data->profit_percentage!=""&&$data->profit_percentage>0){
        $count = $count+1;
    }
}

if($count>0){
    echo "profit is exists for atleast one user";
}
else{
    echo "profit does not exists";
}
```

And your array is stdClass Object thats why `$data->profit_percentage` not `$data['profit_percentage']`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the array object and check `profit_percentage is not empty`like this

```
    <?php

    $status =0;
    foreach($loop as $row )
    {
       if($row->profit_percentage !="" && $row->profit_percentage>0)
       {
             $status =1;
             break;
       }

    }

    echo "status is ".$status;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `foreach` loop ans `isset`.

```
<?php
class Data {
    var $name;
    var $percentage;

    function set_name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function set_percentage($p) {
        $this->percentage = $p;
    }
}

$a = new Data();
$a->set_name("ASD");
//$a->set_percentage(56);

$b = new Data();
$b->set_name("erw");
$b->set_percentage(56);

$p = array($a, $b);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($p);

$status = false;
foreach ($p as $item) {
    if (isset($item-> percentage)) {
        $status = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo $status? "profit exists":"profit does not exists";


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the array through a loop and check if profit_percentage is not empty. Take a flag with initial value 0 and update the flag with 1 if you found any value in profit_percentage.

```
Example code
Here is your array:
$myarray = Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 29
        [name] => User1
        [activated] => 1
        [profit_percentage] => 50
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 23
        [name] => User2
        [activated] => 1
        [profit_percentage] => 
    ) 
 )


Loop to parse the array
$profitFlag = 0; 
foreach($myarray as $val) {
  if($val->profit_percentage!='') {
     $profitFlag = 1;
  }
}
if($profitFlag==1) {
  echo 'profit is exists for atleast one user';
}
```